# How can i investigate what duration a specific checksum had when it was sent out

Tags: checksum

I need to check on some checksums to confirm if the duration matched the setting (which we had set at 90 days but mysteriously was showing as '7' again when i went to check the Misc. settings. Can anyone tell me which table the data is in?

Should this find it for me - if so I guess the field has an unrelated name

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%checksum%'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='<my-database>';
```

Comment: I don't think the checksum is stored in DB, have a look at `CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact_Utils` class more specifically to the `generateChecksum` and `validChecksum` methods https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php#L158

Comment: @Andrei you are correct - can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

The checksum is not stored in the database, have a look at `CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact_Utils` more specifically at the methods [generateChecksum](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php#L158) and [validChecksum](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php#L222).

The `genereateChecksum` method returns the checksum like `$checksum_$timestamt_$life` the life is in hours, so for a given checksum you could tell when was generated and what was is expire date.

The `validChecksum` method takes the `$contact_id` and a `$checksum`  And validates it. This method is called when a profile/contribution/event/etc page is rendered and is taken from the requested URL.

Comment: Andrei - thank you very much. do you know does this mean if there is a way that i can investigate whether a specific checksum that was sent out had a 7 day or a 90 day life

Comment: If you know the actual checksum yes, the last bit (after the second `_` underscore) is the lifetime of that checksum in hours, ie `cs=a135dc716e4e859155cf1123c11bcc27_1464650985_168` 168 / 24 hours = 7 days